# creating exponentially decaying beams on a matlab plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I am having some trouble figuring out how to create these beams in my plot in matlab.

[image]

I have created this graphic that I need to use before the beams are added, but I am not sure how to proceed.

The beams should decay (or attenuate) exponentially from the surface with a decay constant of 15 cm. So, if a surface tile has energy energy value `1`, at depth `i`, where `i` represents the depth in centimeters, the value should be `exp(-i/15)`. Note that the beams should cover the entire extent of the middle square.

the graphic:

[image]

My code for this graphic:

```
Rows = 30;
Cols = 40;
body = zeros(Rows, Cols);
clims = [-1 1];
imagesc(body, clims);
hold on
x = 0:5:40;
y = 0:5:30;
imagesc(x, y, body)
axis([0 40 0 30])
axis xy
shading flat
colorbar
hold on
plot([18, 22],[13, 13],'k')
hold on
plot([18, 18],[13, 17],'k')
hold on
plot([18, 22],[17, 17],'k')
hold on
plot([22, 22],[13, 17],'k')
```

Any help would be so much appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand, you want to recreate the first figure attached and you can't? Can you write mathematically how the function that you want to plot looks like? i.e. `f(x,y)=...`

Comment: Are you trying to combine two vectors into a matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few ways to do this. Basically, you want to set the values in your body before you plot them. Here's one example of a similar curve, I'll let you figure out how to extrapolate it to your exact needs.

```
Rows = 30;
Cols = 40;
body = zeros(Rows, Cols);
xsize=size(body,1);
ysize=size(body,2);
for x=1:xsize
   for y=1:ysize
      body(x,y)=exp((y-ysize/2)*(x-xsize/2));
   end
end
x = 0:5:40;
y = 0:5:30;
imagesc(x, y, body)
```